# Правильно ли я понял задачу?

Tags: c++, ряды

Найти сумму ряда с точностью =10, общий член которого а=2*n!/(3n)!

Как-то дошел до такого кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

double Sum(double eps) {
    double s, an;
    int n;
    n = 1;
    an = 1.0 / 3.0;// a1=(2*1!)/(3!)
    s = 0;
    while (fabs(an) > eps) {
        s += an;
        n++;
        an *= (n + 1.0) / ((3. * n + 1.0) * (3. * n + 2.0) * (3. * n + 3.0));
    }
    return s;
}

int main() {
    double accuracy;
    cout << "accuracy = ";
    cin >> accuracy;
    cout << Sum(accuracy);
    return 0;
}
```

Но теперь не могу понять, откуда я вообще это взял :) Кто может объяснить, сделал ли я правильно.

Comment: Код выглядит правдоподобно, рекуррентная формула выведена правильно. Случайно забыли, как вывести рекуррентную формулу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем-то идея верная, только реализация хромает.

Просто перескажу, что нужно сделать.

В задаче дан ряд, к сожалению,я забыл достаточные и необходимые условия схождения, но очевидно, что при n->inf выражение 2*n!/(3n)! стремится к 0. А значит, можно вычислить ряд до некоторой точности, т.е. наступит такой момент, когда при достаточно большом n новое слагаемое будет меньше заданной точности и соответственно не будет менять значение суммы в пределах этой точности.

Теперь нужно определить зависимость между a(n) и a(n+1); 
для этого нужно разделить a(n+1) / a(n) = ( 2*(n+1)! / (3(n+1))! ) / ( 2n! / (3n)! )

Ты выделил её верно.

a(n+1) = an * ( (n+1) / ( (3*n + 1) * (3*n + 2) * (3*n + 3) );

т.е. должен быть такой ряд: 2*1!/3! + 2*2!/6! + 2*3!/9!;

Затем в цикле, меняя n от 1 до бесконечности, пока новое слагаемое больше заданной точности, как только станет меньше, то всё, на сумму в пределах этой точности оно уже не повлияет.

Одну ошибку я заметил только здесь:

```
n++;
an *= (n + 1.0) / ((3. * n + 1.0) * (3. * n + 2.0) * (3. * n + 3.0));
```

У тебя n -- выше установлено в 1 и для an ты вычислил a1. 
А затем ты вычисляешь новое an т.е. a2, но n увеличиваешь перед этим. И выходит, что ты пропускаешь a2 и вычисляешь сразу a3, и тоже неверно, т.к. умножаешь к a1. Сложно объяснился, но, надеюсь, ты понял. n++ нужно увеличить после вычисления. Либо в формуле везде вместо n использовать (n-1).

Comment: Ряд 1/n расходится, хотя после некоторого n новое слагаемое будет меньше заданной точности. Т.е., несмотря на это, оно все равно МОЖЕТ менять значение суммы в пределах любой точности.
Мат. аппарат выбран неверно.

Comment: Ряд 1/n расходится -- это верно. это гармонический ряд. Но необходимое условие сходимости верное. т.е. 1/n -> 0 при n->inf. В ответе я пояснил, что забыл достаточные условия схождения. Но раз вы намекнули, то вот хороший признак Д'аламбера: limit( abs(a(n+1) / a(n) ) ) = q; n->inf, 0 < p < 1; an * ( (n+1) / ( (3n + 1) * (3n + 2) * (3*n + 3) ) -> очевидно, что предел будет меньше 1 (если не очевидно, я могу вычислит);  А для 1/n => limt(1/(n+1) / 1/n) = 1; и признак Д'аламбера при p = 1 не применим.

Comment: (n+1) / ( (3n+1) * (3n+2) * (3n+3) ) -> сходится к 0 при n->inf; 
т.к. "вверху" линейная зависимость от n, а "снизу" зависимость 3-й степени. 
Но это очевидно только тем, кто знает про правило Лопиталя. т.к. нормальный человек скажет что n+1 стремится к бесконечности и (3n+1) * (3n+2) * (3n+3) тоже стремится к бесконечности. А правило Лопиталя гласит, lim( f(x)/g(x) ) = lim( f'(x) / g'(x) ); производная от n+1 = 1; а производная от (3n+1) * (3n+2) * (3n+3) -- это функция 2-й степени от n; и стремится к бесконечности. 1 разделенное на бесконечность равняется 0

Comment: Никто не спорит с тем фактом, что этот ряд сходимый. И что для любого n существует k такое, что все элементы ряда после k-ого будут меньше n. 
Но отсюда не следует, что если все элементы ряда после k-ого меньше n, то и их сумма будет меньше n. А именно это Вы постулируете в своем решении.

Не хватает доказательства того, что наличие k, после которого все элементы меньше n означает, что их сумма будет меньше n. Пример опровержения такого, гармонический ряд, я привел.

Comment: Т.е. Вы доказали, что ряд сходится - ОК, это не вопрос, это очевидно. Вы не доказали, что он сходится достаточно быстро, настолько, что если k-ый элемент меньше n, то сумма всех элементов, начиная с k-ого - тоже меньше n.

Comment: "Затем в цикле, меняя n от 1 до бесконечности, пока новое слагаемое больше заданной точности, как только станет меньше, то всё, на сумму в пределах этой точности оно уже не повлияет."

Вот тот факт, что как только слагаемое меньше заданной точности, то сумма всех слагаемых после него не превысит заданную точность - НЕ ДОКАЗАН. До сих пор. И именно на бездоказанность его я указал в своем первом комментарии.